# CSS filter Property not working properly on Google Chrome, but works perfectly on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

I am making a website, to be more specific a web shop and I used a CSS filter Property for bluring an image,so when I hover over the image the image blurs and a text appears. The problem that I'm having is that the transition works very nice and smooth on mozilla,but on google chrome it's kinda scuffed.I am using CSS grid for my website design.

I dont know how to fix this and is there any solutions for this.

Here is the HTML and CSS code.

```css
   

 .bigPicture{
     display:inline-block;
     position:relative;
    }
    .blur{
     position:absolute;
     top:45%;
     color:white;
     opacity:0;
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
     -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
     transition:all 0.5s ease;
     right:33%;
    }
    .contentPicture{
     -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
     transition:all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .bigPicture:hover img{
     -webkit-filter: blur(5px); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
        filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" /></filter></svg>#filter');
        filter: blur(5px);
    }
    .bigPicture:hover .blur{
     opacity:1;
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    }
```

```html
    <div class="bigPicture">
      <a href="#">
       <div><img class="contentPicture" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" height=300 width=100%></div>
       <div class="blur"><h1>Započnite kupovinu</h1></div>
      </a>
     </div>
```

As you can see when you hover over the image and if you are using google chrome to read my question you can see that the image is moving, but if you do that in mozilla it works perfectly. If anyone can answer me that would be lovely. thank you.

Comment: i currently have the same problem and this seems to be a "new" bug in Chrome (Version 65.0) when using the filter property. every container that gets a filter, is being skewed in a totally strange way. and it doesn't matter what filter you choose. drop-shadow, blur,.. they all result in the same strange skewed container.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Tried the new Google site and it worked as intended. It was probably just the old site does not support it.

Comment: This is so vague that it really belongs as a comment, not an answer.